# How do I center this image?

Tags: html, css

http://www.kidsmartnyc.com/index.html

I tried a few things after I removed the image from the secondary pages but now I can't get the centering back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the power of CSS!

```
<img src="images/art.jpg" alt="" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Answer (score 2):

Please create individual div for image give a style that text-align:center and width:100%;

```
<div class="main">
<div style="text-align:center; width:100%;">    
         <a href="index.html"><img alt="" src="images/art.jpg" style="margin: 0pt auto;"/></a>
</div>

---- /*someother Statements*/
----
----

</div>
```